# Pizza ordering site django

Tags: django

I am creating a Pizza ordering system using Django, and I have 4 fields for my Pizza model. I have already added the different variations into the model (e.g: Regular Small 1 Topping (13.70), Regular Small Cheese (12.70)). Now I need to add toppings based on which addon the user selects. I have a list for all the toppings, but I am not exactly sure what to do now? Could someone guide on what i should do?

```
    SIZES = (
    ("Small", "Small"),
    ("Large", "Large")
)


class Pizza(models.Model):
    #type-size-topping (db)
    STYLES = (
    ('Regular', 'Regular'),
    ('Sicilian', 'Sicilian')
)
    ADDONS = (
    ('Cheese', 'Cheese'),
    ('1 Topping', '1 Topping'),
    ('2 Topping', '2 Toppings'),
    ('3 Topping', '3 Toppings'),
    ('Special', 'Special')
)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STYLES)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SIZES)
    addons = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ADDONS)
    price= models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Pizza"

    def __str__(self):
          return f"{self.type} {self.size} {self.addons} ({self.price})"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably want a many-to-many relationship to another `Toppings` model…

Comment: Add pepperoni and sausage to your list

Answer (score 0):

Create seperate models for the toppings and sizes, as shown in the following code:

```
class Size(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Pizza(models.Model):

    price= models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    topping = models.ForeignKey(Topping, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Pizza"

    def __str__(self):
          return f"{self.type} {self.size} ({self.price})"
```

Comment: Im so sorry, but I am completely new to Django, now what do I do?